# In Visio Professional 2016 my hyperlinks will only launch our Intranet home page, not the specific documents I'm linking to

Tags: hyperlink, microsoft-visio-2016

I've used various ways to insert the document URL into the Visio shape:

- I've pasted the URL into the Address field
- I've tried with and without 'Use relative path for hyperlink'
- I've tried clicking 'Browse' instead of pasting the URL; the document or page opens but
  nothing happens
- I've deleted all hyperlinks and started again
- I've tried attaching the link to actual text within the shape and also to the shape itself.

I've had the same problem in the past, with the same Visio document. After all the same fiddling as above, it eventually worked.

Today I've updated the document and links not working again.

I'm only inserting one hyperlink into each shape.

I've pasted the same URLs into a Word doc and the link works perfectly.
This is urgent COVID-19 clinical information and I really need it to work asap.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Are you using a full URL ... http://somethingsomethingsomething etc or just www.somethingsomethingsomething?

Comment: Thanks Paul - I was using the whole URL (https//something something) which I copied the same way I always do hyperlinks in all my documents)